# What's the "farm area" in the final mission?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

One of the challenges in the last mission is to kill the HVTs in the farm area within 3 seconds. What's that mean? I thought that it meant to kill the first two people within three seconds of each other, but I'm pretty sure I did that with my sync shot, and it didn't say I did the challenge. Were those the wrong guys, or is that not what it means by three seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the middle three people, but you are right on how on how to kill them:

> Tactic: Mark the 3 HVTs for your teammates and give the command for a synched shot. All of them will be dead within a second. If you have problems to locate one of the HVTs then throw motion sensors.

[Source](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=371479)

Also watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-G_Aq9N8TMg#t=583s) on how to do it.